# Unable to start mysql after restarting server

Tags: mysql

I restarted server where mysql is installed since then it is not getting started below is the error log i got when the try to start mysqld service.I checked whether any mysqld_safe is running using **ps ax | grep mysql** seems nothing is running

```
160506 08:54:53 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
160506 08:54:59 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /data/mysql
160506  8:54:59 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ambiguous option '--i' (ignore-builtin-innodb, interactive_timeout)
160506  8:54:59 [ERROR] Aborting

160506 08:54:59 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

My.cnf

```
    [mysqld]
server-id=832
#datadir=/var/lib/mysql
#datadir=/database/mysql/data
datadir=/data/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Default to using old password format for compatibility with mysql 3.x
# clients (those using the mysqlclient10 compatibility package).
old_passwords=1
lower_case_table_names=1
max_connections=2048
#check
# this happens when max_allowed_packet=1M but not when max_allowed_packet=2M,
i# actually 1638400 is already fine
max_allowed_packet=1024M
key_buffer=128M
max_user_connections=32768
tmp_table_size=128M
table_cache=524288 # old value is 1024M
query_cache_size=512M
query_cache_type=1
sort_buffer=128M
join_buffer_size=32M
read_buffer=128M
#set-variable    = write_buffer=128M  Timeout occurs if opened this
#record_buffer=128M old parameter please use read_buffer_size instead
read_buffer_size=512M # old value is 128M
myisam_sort_buffer_size=64M
myisam_max_sort_file_size=2G
back_log=100
interactive_timeout=10000
wait_timeout=1000
connect_timeout=1000
net_read_timeout=1000
open_files_limit=30000
thread_concurrency=512
thread_cache_size=16384 #old value is 128M
thread_stack=8M

#end of check

## extra parameters verify and remove
#TransactionDeadlockDetectionTimeout=100  Notworking
#HeartbeatIntervalDbDb=3000
#HeartbeatIntervalDbApi=3000
#innodb_buffer_pool_size=4096M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=1G
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=512M
innodb_thread_concurrency=0
innodb_file_per_table=1
sort_buffer=128M
#log_slow_queries=ON
slow_query_log=/database/mysql/log/slowlog
max_sp_recursion_depth=5
## upto Here

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-installing mysql binaries does the job for me